# Delete all numbers from a text using PHP or JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a .txt file that contains a list of names and some numbers.
For example,

---

AARON   0.24     350,151    77

ABDUL   0.007    10,213 831

ABE 0.006    8,754  854

---

and on...

So, I need to delete ALL numbers from that list using PHP or JavaScript with returning words from the list.

P.S.: I'm just learning these languages so, please, answer concretely- with full code and with its place.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) I don't intend to sound harsh, but how do you expect to "learn" these languages by letting other people write code for you :)

Comment: and remember, you can't use JavaScript to do it. Only PHP in your case

Comment: I have tried some PHP and JS variants(all of them work only with 1 string). The problem is there are over 1200 strings in this file and i need to delete numbers from them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you actually want to delete everything that's not an alphabetic character. To do so, use this:

```
$text = 'AARON 0.24 350,151 77';
$text = preg_replace( '#[^a-z]#i', '', $text);
```

This is a regular expression which will replace any character that is not A-Z or a-z with an empty string (nothing).

All you need is this:

```
$lines = file( 'Types.txt');
foreach( $lines as &$line)
    $line = preg_replace( '#[^a-z]#i', '', $line);
echo implode( "\n", $lines);
```

Comment: I have a huge list wiht many strings, is it possible to delete numbers from the whole list? There are over 1200 strings

Comment: You have a text file, right? So read the text file with `$text = file_get_contents( 'file.txt');`, then you have the variable `$text` which you can use with the 2nd line in my post, and you're done.

Comment: @Vlad - It is complete, see my answer.

Comment: I've just tried this:
`<?
$text = file_get_contents( 'Types.txt');
$text = preg_replace( '#[^a-z]#i', '', $text);
echo $text;
?>`
It works, but the answer is just a line of words without spaces. How can I make a result as a vertical list of names?

Comment: I've updated my answer - If this still doesn't work, change `"\n"` to `"<br />"`.

Comment: Now I've finally made it.
But I used another method, because "<br />" means exchanging **every** number into a newline. You helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript version looks like this.

```
var strings = ["AARON 0.24 350,151 77", "ABDUL 0.007 10,213 831", "ABE 0.006 8,754 854"],
newStrings = '';

for (var i=0,len=strings.length; i<len; i++){
newStrings = strings[i].match(/[A-z]+/g);
alert(newStrings);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but shouldn't `newStrings` be an array as well, though?